# What are the consequences of not disclosing all Conflicts of Interests (COI)?

Tags: publications, conflict-of-interest

This is in follow-up with this question:

[Clear explanation of Conflict of Interest with examples in journal articles](https://academia.stackexchange.com/questions/56978/clear-explanation-of-conflict-of-interest-with-examples-in-journal-articles)

Apart from what it really is, it keeps me thinking why should authors disclose possible conflict of interests (for the publications that require them)? 
To be clear, what could happen if they don't? Is it anything to do with unethical conduct or does stating them support the authors in any way?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

According to the Committee on Publication Ethics, retraction is a possibility.  See their [Retraction Guidelines](http://publicationethics.org/files/retraction%20guidelines.pdf), page 2:

> Retractions are also used to alert readers to [...] failure to disclose a major competing interest likely to influence
>   interpretations or recommendations.

The Retraction Watch blog [has questioned](http://retractionwatch.com/2016/07/11/should-a-paper-be-retracted-if-an-author-omits-a-conflict-of-interest/#more-42007) how often this is carried out in practice.

Comment: So who would be the one to file the claim in the first place? Could you give a brief example?

Comment: @ÉbeIsaac: Presumably it could be anybody who was aware of the competing interest.